# Trying to do JUnit testing on a java hibernate application, and I'm getting a NullPointerAcception

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven

I'm making an application in Java using Hibernate, Maven, and JUnit for testing. I've had quite a few errors, and my latest one is a nullpointerexception that I'm not seeing any obvious fixes for. Please let me know if I accidentally left out any helpful information (the terminal output?). The exception occurs when I try to test the getById method in the PcBuildDao class.

the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at persistence.PcBuildDaoTest.getById(PcBuildDaoTest.java:24)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:389)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:163)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:110)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:83)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hardwareviewer</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>

        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">student</property>

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>

        <mapping class="entity.PcBuild" />
        <mapping class="entity.User" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="[url I can't post here]"
      xsi:schemaLocation="[here too]">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>edu.matc.entjava.hardwareviewer</groupId>
  <artifactId>hardwareviewer</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>hardwareviewer Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>https://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>

    <javax.version>7.0</javax.version>
    <mysql-version>8.0.16</mysql-version>
    <jstl-version>1.2</jstl-version>
    <log4j-version>2.10.0</log4j-version>
    <jupiter-version>5.0.0</jupiter-version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <junit-platform-runner-version>1.0.0</junit-platform-runner-version>
    <junit-vintage-version>4.12.0</junit-vintage-version>
    <hibernate-core-version>5.4.4.Final</hibernate-core-version>
    <hibernate-c3p0-version>5.4.4.Final</hibernate-c3p0-version>

    <javb-api.version>2.3.1</javb-api.version>

    <maven-compiler-plugin-version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin-version>2.19</maven-surefire-plugin-version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
      <version>${javax.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java  -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>${mysql-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>${jstl-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${jupiter-version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-platform-runner-version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-vintage-version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate-core-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate-c3p0-version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>${javb-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>hardwareviewer</finalName>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3</version>
          <configuration>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <webResources>
              <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp/META-INF</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
              </resource>
            </webResources>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${maven-surefire-plugin-version}</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
              <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
              <version>${junit-platform-runner-version}</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

PcBuild POJO

```
package entity;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity(name = "PcBuild")
@Table(name = "computer_builds")
public class PcBuild {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    private int buildId;

    @Column(name = "cpu_model")
    private String cpuModel;

    @Column(name = "gpu_model")
    private String gpuModel;

    @Column(name = "cpu_cooler_model")
    private String cpuCoolerModel;

    @Column(name = "Motherboard_model")
    private String motherboardModel;

    @Column(name = "psu_model")
    private String psuModel;

    @Column(name = "case_model")
    private String caseModel;

    @Column(name = "data_storage_model")
    private String dataStorageModel;

    @Column(name = "ram_model")
    private String ramModel;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "userId")
    private User user;

    public PcBuild() {
    }

    public PcBuild(int buildId, String cpuModel, String gpuModel,
            String cpuCoolerModel, String motherboardModel, String psuModel,
            String caseModel, String dataStorageModel, String ramModel,
            User user) {
        this.buildId = buildId;
        this.cpuModel = cpuModel;
        this.gpuModel = gpuModel;
        this.cpuCoolerModel = cpuCoolerModel;
        this.motherboardModel = motherboardModel;
        this.psuModel = psuModel;
        this.caseModel = caseModel;
        this.dataStorageModel = dataStorageModel;
        this.ramModel = ramModel;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public int getBuildId() {
        return buildId;
    }

    public void setBuildId(int buildId) {
        this.buildId = buildId;
    }

    public String getCpuModel() {
        return cpuModel;
    }

    public void setCpuModel(String cpuModel) {
        this.cpuModel = cpuModel;
    }

    public String getGpuModel() {
        return gpuModel;
    }

    public void setGpuModel(String gpuModel) {
        this.gpuModel = gpuModel;
    }

    public String getCpuCoolerModel() {
        return cpuCoolerModel;
    }

    public void setCpuCoolerModel(String cpuCoolerModel) {
        this.cpuCoolerModel = cpuCoolerModel;
    }

    public String getMotherboardModel() {
        return motherboardModel;
    }

    public void setMotherboardModel(String motherboardModel) {
        this.motherboardModel = motherboardModel;
    }

    public String getPsuModel() {
        return psuModel;
    }

    public void setPsuModel(String psuModel) {
        this.psuModel = psuModel;
    }

    public String getCase_Model() {
        return caseModel;
    }

    public void setCase_Model(String caseModel) {
        this.caseModel = caseModel;
    }

    public String getDataStorageModel() {
        return dataStorageModel;
    }

    public void setDataStorageModel(String dataStorageModel) {
        this.dataStorageModel = dataStorageModel;
    }

    public String getRamModel() {
        return ramModel;
    }

    public void setRamModel(String ramModel) {
        this.ramModel = ramModel;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUserId(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PcBuild{" +
                "buildId=" + buildId +
                ", cpuModel='" + cpuModel + '\'' +
                ", gpuModel='" + gpuModel + '\'' +
                ", cpuCoolerModel='" + cpuCoolerModel + '\'' +
                ", motherboardModel='" + motherboardModel + '\'' +
                ", psuModel='" + psuModel + '\'' +
                ", caseModel='" + caseModel + '\'' +
                ", dataStorageModel='" + dataStorageModel + '\'' +
                ", ramModel='" + ramModel + '\'' +
                ", user=" + user +
                '}';
    }
}
```

PcBuild DAO

```
package persistence;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import entity.PcBuild;

public class PcBuildDao {
    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactoryProvider.getSessionFactory();

    public PcBuild getById(int id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        PcBuild pcBuild = session.get(PcBuild.class, id);
        session.close();
        return pcBuild;
    }

    public void saveOrUpdatePcBuild(PcBuild pcBuild) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(pcBuild);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }

    public int insert(PcBuild pcBuild) {
        int id = 0;
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        id = (int) session.save(pcBuild);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
        return id;
    }

    public void delete(PcBuild pcBuild) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(pcBuild);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

User POJO

```
package entity;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity(name = "User")
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    private int userId;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<PcBuild> pcBuilds = new HashSet<>();

    public User() {
    }

    public User(int userId, String username, String password, Set<PcBuild> pcBuilds) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.pcBuilds = pcBuilds;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Set<PcBuild> getPcBuilds() {
        return pcBuilds;
    }

    public void setPcBuilds(Set<PcBuild> pcBuilds) {
        this.pcBuilds = pcBuilds;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "userId=" + userId +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

User DAO

```
package persistence;

import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Expression;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import entity.User;

public class UserDao {
    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactoryProvider.getSessionFactory();

    public User getById(int id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> query = builder.createQuery(User.class);
        Root<User> root = query.from(User.class);
        Expression<String> propertyPath = root.get("id");
        query.where(builder.equal(propertyPath, id));
        User user = session.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
        session.close();
        return user;
    }

    public void saveOrUpdate(User user) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(user);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }

    public int insert(User user) {
        int id = 0;
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        id = (int)session.save(user);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
        return id;
    }

    public void delete(User user) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(user);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

The mySQL script I run before every test

```
delete from computer_builds;

delete from users;

insert into users (userId, username, password) VALUES (1, 'fchristian', 'student');

insert into users (userId, username, password) VALUES (2, 'achristian', 'lollipop');

insert into computer_builds (cpu_model, gpu_model, cpu_cooler_model, motherboard_model, psu_model, case_model,
                             data_storage_model, ram_model, userId)
values ('Ryzen 7 5800X3D', 'PowerColor Red Devil OC Radeon RX 6950 XT', 'Deepcool AK620', 'MSI MAG B550 Tomahawk',
        'Thermaltake Toughpower GF1 PE 850 W', 'Corsair 4000D Airflow ATX Mid Tower', 'Samsung 970 Evo Plus 2 TB NVMe SSD',
        'Corsair Vengeance LPX 16 GB (2 x 8 GB) DDR4-3600 CL18', 1);

insert into computer_builds (cpu_model, gpu_model, cpu_cooler_model, motherboard_model, psu_model, case_model,
                             data_storage_model, ram_model, userId)
values ('Ryzen 3 3200G', 'Gigabyte GAMING OC Radeon RX 5700 XT', 'Stock', 'Gigabyte B450M DS3H Wifi',
        'Fractal Design Ion SFX 650 W', 'Thermaltake Core G3 ATX Mid Tower', 'Teamgroup GX2 512 GB SSD',
        'Corsair Vengeance LPX 16 GB (2 x 8 GB) DDR4-3200 CL16', 2);
```

I tried running the getById method in the PcBuildDao by passing in "1" and apparently it's just returning nothing instead of the returned PcBuild object's GPU model which I'm trying to get by calling its getGpuModel method.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  First of all, your example is waaaay too long and complicated.  You need to boil it down.  Also, you should always include the exception if you are getting one because it provides critical information about where the NPE is happening.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Gray I figured more info is better than too little. I'll keep that in mind. Meanwhile, I added the exception